# Reading Pointer to a pointer value is crashing in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, pointers, android-ndk

I am trying to send a pointer to pointer ptr in the function . ptr

```
    int ret = funcptrptr(unsigned char** ptr);
```

Inside funcptrptr() i am assigning a new value of information to ptrptr . I even print the contents and it seems to be printing

On return from this function call am trying to dereference the ptrptr to p like below,

```
  unsigned char* p = *ptr;
```

This is crashing with SIGEGV . Why ?

Code inside funcptrptr() goes some thing like this

```
*ptrptr  = u_build_value(crypted_vector,random_vector);
```

Inside  function u_build_value am actually allocating using malloc and returning back the contents as unsigned char *

=========

The solution was allocating memory to **ptrptr** variable as pointed out by some one below. it worked. thanks .

Comment: it is crashing with SIGEGV . This is on Android NDK.  corrected typos

Comment: Why are you voting down . huh can you explain atleast why ? If you are not expert then why vote down

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you don't show enough of the code, which means that we can't really tell you want's going on, and so can't answer your question. It's likely this will be closed soon too because of that.

Comment: That could also mean i cannot share my code as it is proprietary. And am looking for some better expert who can understand pretty much well. So dont answer my question and move on. what is the point of this forum after all if people like you without thinking misuse the voting down !! i am genuinely in the middle of finding answer .

Comment: You don't have to show *all* the code, just enough to get a sense of what you do. For example, show the involved variable declarations and *how you call the function*. It doesn't even have to be the real variable-names, just something generic.

Comment: @rana No body is interested in or asking your _proprietary_ code. But simply a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg never mind. There are plenty of others who can help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you didn't do anything before calling `u_build_value`, you are trying to dereference a pointer that doesn't point to anything on this line:

```
*ptrptr  = u_build_value(crypted_vector,random_vector); 
^here your are dereferencing a pointer causing undefined behaviour
```

Change your code to: `ptrptr  = u_build_value(crypted_vector,random_vector);` or allocate some memory for `ptrptr` if you want to dereference it.

Comment: I am actually allocating a memory inside u_build_value and returning content back and assigning it to my *ptrptr.

Comment: i edited . u_build_value is returning an unsigned char*. So am not doing anything wrong . I am not sure where i am going wrong

Comment: @rana Here: `*ptrptr`  Look at the `*` and think what it does.

Comment: I think that is the issue. I should allocate a memory for ptrptr. Thanks for pointing out !